# iOS 7+ UISearchBar cancel button has unwanted alpha on highlighted state

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, alpha

I have UISearchBar with cancel button. Cancel button has custom backgroundImage for normal and highlighted states sets in appDelegate:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[<someNormalImage> resizableImageWithCapInsets:<someedges>] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[<someHighlightedImage> resizableImageWithCapInsets:<someedges>] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Everything works fine. Images are showing, except of highlighted state, where backgroundImage is showed with unwanted alpha (opacity). 
When button is highlighted, highlighted background blink and then opacity is changed.
I wasn't able to find any answers to this problem, only how to change appearance of cancel button (which is working well).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any update on this? I have the same issue with barbuttonitems

Comment: Nope. BTW problem is only iOS 7+. IOS 6 is working.